# LDAP-based RBAC using newer versions of spring-security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ldap, rbac

### Goal

Given a `/secure` endpoint that requires an LDAP user to be in the `admin` group, how do I check their granted authorities using more current versions of spring security?

### Background

Here's a [github repo](https://github.com/samayer12/spring-ldap-poc) with a reproducible example of LDAP authentication with an openLDAP container. At tag [pre-upgrade](https://github.com/samayer12/spring-ldap-poc/tree/pre-upgrade), you can authenticate as `unauthorized` but cannot view the `/secure` endpoint. At the current commit on [main](https://github.com/samayer12/spring-ldap-poc/tree/995f0aca09480da4dce85c8262dfb958f0ca9c96), `unauthorized` can authenticate and view `/secure`, which it not desired.

In the upgrade, changes to the `ldapAuthoritiesPopulator()` probably cause the issue. You can view the diff between `main` and `pre-upgrade` [here](https://github.com/samayer12/spring-ldap-poc/compare/7bf69c3e..main#diff-8aea6551c0dd1ff124ff9a78088484ed6feb579c988802bcb4c54ab844cc20a3), take a look at `SecurityConfig.java`.

An internal method (`getGroupMembershipRoles()`) for `ldapAuthoritiesPopulator()` did the roles check, but after upgrading it looks like that function was [removed](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/LdapAuthoritiesPopulator.html). *Where should the logic for securing endpoints based upon LDAP group membership go instead?*

### Related Resources

- [Document how to publish an AuthenticationManager @Bean without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter - #11926](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11926)
- [LDAP Authentication with Embedded server](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter#ldap-authentication)
- [Spring LDAP Docs - Attribute Access with DirContextAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/dirobjectfactory.html)

### Authentication Log Output

- Pre-Upgrade - `authorized` user logs in, followed by `unauthorized` user

```
10:22:07.156 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN  org.example.LoggerListener - Authentication event AuthenticationSuccessEvent: authorized; details: WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=A978FE05724BD750548AD8148347D665]
10:22:07.157 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN  org.example.LoggerListener - Authentication event SessionFixationProtectionEvent: authorized; details: WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=A978FE05724BD750548AD8148347D665]
10:22:07.157 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN  org.example.LoggerListener - Authentication event InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent: authorized; details: WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=A978FE05724BD750548AD8148347D665]
10:23:43.668 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] WARN  org.example.LoggerListener - Authentication event AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent: unauthorized; details: WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=65900F1284AA62D158BCA96A22D3744A]; exception: User must be a member of ROLE_ADMIN
```

- Post-Upgrade - `authorized` user logs in, followed by `unauthorized` user

```
10:15:24.101 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] WARN  org.example.LoggerListener - Authentication event SessionFixationProtectionEvent: authorized; authorities: []; details: WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=E3CDB4A1CF9B3766A5DB70F9D7C50586]
10:15:24.102 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] WARN  org.example.LoggerListener - Authentication event InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent: authorized; authorities: []; details: WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=E3CDB4A1CF9B3766A5DB70F9D7C50586]
10:25:38.098 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN  org.example.LoggerListener - Authentication event SessionFixationProtectionEvent: unauthorized; authorities: []; details: WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=10D2AD100DDFF5CB15FDE5526BE85722]
10:25:38.098 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN  org.example.LoggerListener - Authentication event InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent: unauthorized; authorities: []; details: WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=10D2AD100DDFF5CB15FDE5526BE85722]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do was call `factory.setLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(contextSource));` within `authenticationManager()`.

The POC repo has been updated with [these changes](https://github.com/samayer12/spring-ldap-poc/commit/6deea476c71afe96ca3267317542abcf046ef816), you can clone and run that to see the desired outcome.